# Visual Studio 11 compile-time error using std::map

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-errors

The following code compiles with gcc-4.5.1 but not in Visual Studio 11.

```
#include <map>
#include <array>

typedef std::pair<const unsigned int, std::array<const unsigned int, 4>> pairus;

int main(){

   std::map<const unsigned int, std::array<const unsigned int, 4> > x; 
   std::array<const unsigned int, 4> troll = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   x.insert(pairus(1, troll));

   auto z = x[1];
}
```

1 is now mapped to `std::array<> troll`. The insertion works well and the program compiles. But, as soon as i try `auto z = x[1]` -> Therefore trying to get the array troll that `1` is mapped to, the program does not compile with the following error:

`error C2512: 'std::array<_Ty,_Size>::array'` : no appropriate default constructor available

What causes this difference in behavior between gcc and vs11 and how to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `pairus` shouldn't be `make_pair`?  (Don't think that's your problem though)

Comment: Yeah it works just fine with pairus being of type std::pair<>. This weird compiler behavior is driving me bonkers tho.

Comment: What does pairus look like (assuming it's a custom function?  or is it MSVC++'s alias of make_pair?).  I suspect the problem may lie in pairus because there is no need for a default constructor anywhere in the code you posted.  (Though a default ctor would be needed if you did x[k] where k is not in the map.)

Comment: @Corbin: He defined pairus in his own code, above main.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oh my...  It's the name of the typedef.  I feel dumb now.  Ermmm...  Ignore my previous comments.  x.x

Comment: pairus is simply a typpedef on std::pair<...>, I could simply x.insert(std::pair<const uint, std::array<const uint, 4>>(1, troll)) ...

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Yeah, sorry about that. I apparently lost the ability to read for a few minutes there.

Comment: Have you tried `auto z(x[1]);`?

Comment: @n.m. Yes i have, it doesn't compile that way either. I also tried not auto-ing but declaring the type myself ...

Comment: Note that the same error occurs with the single line: ` std::array<const unsigned int, 4> another_troll;` ... No need for the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `auto z = *x.find(1);` instead. The `[]`-operator requires a default-constructible type. In fact, the entire container requires a default-constructible type, so you really can't expect anything but random luck as you try out various implementations.

Comment: You're a genius! :) Works! :) Gcc appears to know some arcane magic. Thanks ;)

Comment: Not sure the default constructor requirement stands for the whole container now that C++11 is passed.  The new map needs to be able to hold movable types, but only some of the functionality is available for them.  The [] operator is not I don't think.

Answer (score 3):

Your type is not assignable because it contains constants.

x[1] tries to return a reference that is assignable.  It will also construct an empty value for the key if it's not there yet.  Both of these are invalid with your type.  You'll have to use find instead.

Comment: Why on earth would gcc compile the thing then :) ?

Comment: The standard only states what is required, it doesn't state what is allowed.  Some manner in which the gcc implementation works doesn't cause the same problem in your special case.  It's free to do this.  There's no diagnostic requirements here.